# how to catch SqlException error inside my asp.net mvc

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the following action method:

```
[Authorize]
    public ActionResult CustomersDetails(long[] SelectRight)
    {
        if (SelectRight == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("customer", new { isError = true });
        }
        else
        {
            try 
            {
                var ContactsDetails2 = new ContactsDetails
                    {
                        Info = r.getcontactinfo(SelectRight)
                    };

                foreach (var x in ContactsDetails2.Info)
                {
                    ViewData[x.USER_ID.ToString()] = r.getorgname(x.USER_ID).ToString();
                }

                return View(ContactsDetails2);
            }
            catch (SqlException)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Too many records will be returned, please try to minimize your selection and try again.");
                return RedirectToAction("customer", "Home");
             }
         }            
      }
```

and the following method:

```
public IEnumerable<AaaUserContactInfo> getcontactinfo(long[] id)
        {
            var organizationsiteids = from accountsitemapping in entities.AccountSiteMappings
                      where id.Any(accountid => accountsitemapping.ACCOUNTID == accountid)
                                       select accountsitemapping.SITEID;
//code goes here
```

Now if the getcontactinfo raise the folloiwng exception:-

> [SqlException (0x80131904): Some part of your SQL statement is nested
>   too deeply. Rewrite the query or break it up into smaller queries.]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +388
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +688
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +4403
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData() +82
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +135

.... the  `**catch (SqlException)**` willnot be reached ?

Answer (score 1):

Change `catch (SqlException)` to `catch (Exception ex)`.

You probably get another kind of exception, before `SqlException` happens.